# gitlab ci throwing error for angular project

Tags: angular, gitlab-ci, node-sass

I have recently started getting error for my CI in gitlab-ci for my angular project

The error is as follows

```
$ npm install --unsafe-perm -g --save-dev @angular/cli@1.3.2
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/linux_musl-x64-59_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/linux_musl-x64-59_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

I know that the file `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/linux_musl-x64-59_binding.node`doesn't exist, but I am not sure why `node-sass` is trying to install that version of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the node versioning. In my gitlab-ci I was using the latest node docker image (`node:alpine`) and `node:alpine` tag has been moved to node version `9.x.x` as of 31st October 2017. Hence, this broke node-sass as [node-sass only supports upto 8.X.X](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/1969/files/f783a9c57e537e45aab17ae211007ffd4ab121f9#diff-40fa1bcc04a39e465f1572b1178dfcfb) as of version `4.5.3`

I switched my node docker image to `node:carbon-alpine` which supports node `8.X.X` and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First clear npm cache :

```
npm cache clean
```

Then install node-sass globally :

```
npm install -g node-sass@4.5.3
```

Then run your command :

```
npm install --unsafe-perm -g --save-dev @angular/cli@1.3.2
```

---

If it still not works , then try to install it with [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) :

```
yarn add node-sass
```

And then run your command